# FTDI 232H Communication

Tags: usb, ftdi

I was wondering if anyone might be experiencing/have experienced the same communication issue that I am having with my FTDI FT232H module.

I am sending a character to the USB module and then using my microcontroller's debugger to see if the correct character is being transmitted. For the most part, all characters work except for a few, specifcally "g,o,s, and w". These sometimes work... but sometimes they don't. It's very inconsistent and I'm having a hard time isolating what the problem may be, please let me know if there is anything I can do, or if more details are needed.

P.S The module is being run in 245 async FIFO mode.

Regards!

Comment: My crystal ball says: Internal RC oscillator and no quarz, incorrect baud rate because frequency is a bit off too much.